# Easypermissions does not return to Method

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using the library Easypermissions to ask for permissions at runtime.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private final int RC_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private final String[] fineLocationPerms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

private String searchTag = "";

private void checkLocationForPoiSearch( String tag) throws  SecurityException {
    if(hasLocationPermissions()) {
       .....
    } else {
        this.searchTag = tag ;
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "test", RC_FINE_LOCATION, fineLocationPerms);
    }
}

@AfterPermissionGranted(RC_FINE_LOCATION)
protected void permissionsGranted() {
    Log.d(TAG, "permissions granted");
    checkLocationForPoiSearch(this.searchTag);
}

 private boolean hasLocationPermissions() {
    boolean hasPermissions = false ;

    if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this.getContext(), fineLocationPerms)) {
        hasPermissions = true;
    }

    return hasPermissions;
}

}
```

My expectation is that Easypermissions will call the method permissionsGranted after the user has given the appropriate permissions. But for some reasons the method permissionsGranted will not be called. So any idea what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after some debugging I got the solution. You have to override the following method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}
```